# Azure VisualSearch fails with Unauthorized despite valid key

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

I feel I must be missing something obvious here. I've been trying to follow the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-visual-search/quickstarts/sdk/visual-search-client-library-csharp. I created a "Bing Search" service in Azure with the S9 tier which supports Visual Search. I went to the Keys and Endpoint section and copied the Key 1 out and put it in the below code, yet every time I run it I get `Unauthorized`:

```
{"code":"401","message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource."}
```

```cs
var client = new VisualSearchClient(new Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Search.VisualSearch.ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials("<key>"));

ImageInfo ImageInfo = new ImageInfo(url: "https://media.vanityfair.com/photos/5d9f5be40fa2040008f28470/4:3/w_1776,h_1332,c_limit/always-sunny-in-philadelphia-hangs-in-there.jpg");
VisualSearchRequest VisualSearchRequest = new VisualSearchRequest(imageInfo: ImageInfo);

var result = await client.Images.VisualSearchMethodAsync(knowledgeRequest: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(VisualSearchRequest));
```

The instructions don't say anything about setting an endpoint, but I tried that too, setting the Endpoint property from the one in my Keys and Endpoint page:

`client.Endpoint = "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/";`

But that just result in a `NotFound` error.

Anyone have any idea what's going on? I tried both keys with no success. Here's a LINQPad repro of the issue: http://share.linqpad.net/c3p8vo.linq

Thanks!

Comment: Filed an issue at GitHub as well, I think this may be a bug https://github.com/microsoft/bing-search-sdk-for-net/issues/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-visual-search/quickstarts/sdk/visual-search-client-library-csharp) is actually wrong (as of 8/9/22). It says

> The NuGet Visual Search package.
> From the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, right-click on your project and select Manage NuGet Packages from the menu. Install the **Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Search.VisualSearch** package.

But that's the old nuget package, which has the old endpoint in it: https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com. The new endpoint is https://api.bing.microsoft.com. I found that there's actually another, newer nuget package, `Microsoft.Bing.Search.VisualSearch` which has the correct endpoint, but I can't find documentation *anywhere* pointing to it!

Once I switched to that nuget package though, everything worked as expected when passing an imageUrl. I still can't get it to work with a FileStream though, I think that might be broken as well.

Comment: Tracked by https://github.com/microsoft/bing-search-sdk-for-net/issues/7

Comment: good find, even MS forums did not mention `Microsoft.Bing.Search.VisualSearch`